# org-mode: Set maximum image width limit

Tags: org-mode, images, inline-image

Using `org-image-actual-width` will both downscale and upscale. I just want to downscale big images to fit the current width. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The doc string for `org-image-actual-width` says (among other things):

> When set to nil, try to get the width from an #+ATTR.* keyword
> and fall back on the original width if none is found.

So set it to nil and specify the width with an `#+ATTR` keyword only for the big images that you want to downscale. More info can be found in the manual in the `Exporting` chapter, in section [Images for HTML export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-HTML-export.html#Images-in-HTML-export) and section [Images in LaTeX export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-LaTeX-export.html#Images-in-LaTeX-export).

Comment: This is not automatic downscaling. I'd need to automate adding an ATTR for each inserted image, and even then it would be hardcoded to my current screen resolution.

Comment: I never said it was, but that's the best you can do I believe: Org mode has no idea what the size of an image you give it is - it will either insert it as is (no size spec) or it will set the size you tell it.

Comment: There's no reason org-mode couldn't find out the image size and do something smart though; [org-mode uses](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/5120b612f8520a855fc1819c3ebf86453c361e55/lisp/org/org.el#L16345..L16350) `create-image` which accepts a `:max-width` parameter in PROPS. Could be worth submitting a patch @HappyFace ;-)

Comment: Any update on this? Should we submit an issue somewhere?